# How to manage screen displaying time in iphone for my app?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am creating an iphone application. In which I am needed to keep screen on till 30 mins. If user don't perform any task within that time the light of device in which we can see scree may be down untill user again tap. No matter if light goes dimmed within the 30 min but it should not be fully down? Like Media player if user don't tap on screen we can see screen coz moview is playing. but other screen if user don't interact display light will be down and user need to tap on screen.

Is there any way to do this in iphone sdk.

Please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all to disable dimming use

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

If you want to set appropriate amount of time then you can create an NSTimer with time interval of 30 mins (30*60 sec). When the timer fires you set

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;
```

If user touches the screen you invalidate current timer and start the new one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Can you tell me one more thing that is it possible to test this in simulator or I need to test only in device.